# Draw the charge configuration according to the electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I'm trying to draw the charge configuration outside the regions that lead to the given electric field patterns. Can someone show me how?
[image]

Comment: That is not the question you were supposed to answer as your homework, is it?

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't understand

Comment: Just checking: they are really expecting you to draw a charge configuration that produces this kind of field?

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes, is it too hard or too easy?

Comment: Could you tell us who drew this assignment? Is it out of a textbook?

Comment: @CuriousOne It's just a homework, I don't know where it from

Comment: Maybe I am blanking at the moment, or I am missing an important piece of information, but I don't think this is a physically realizable electric field. That's the reason why I didn't ignore your homework question, to begin with. I hope someone can turn my intuition about this into either a valid physical argument or a proof that I just didn't get enough sleep last night. If, however, my feeling is correct, then they shouldn't have asked you to do something that is not possible.

Comment: @CuriousOne: do you mean to say that it's not realizable as an field with only static charges, because the field is not conservative, or equivalently, its integral on some closed paths isn't zero?

Comment: @b_jonas: Yep. Like I said, I am blanking at the moment for an argument why it isn't realizable, but everything in me screams that this doesn't look right. I'll appreciate an intellectual kick, so I'll wake up. :-) If one were to place charges as sources at the beginning and end points of the field lines, the result would look nothing like this for sure. So what's going on here? Field lines don't cross, right?

Comment: @CuriousOne This image should be tilted to the left by 90 degrees, if that will make any difference

Comment: @CuriousOne, the field is not irrotational so it certainly isn't an electrostatic field.

Answer (score 4):

Using cylindrical coordinates with the origin at the center and the $\phi = 0$ direction 'down' (the OP says the image should be rotated CCW 90 degrees), the electric field appears be have only a radial component with a sign change for $\phi = \frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$$\vec E = E(\rho,\phi)\hat\rho $$

$$E(\rho,\phi) = E_{\rho}(\rho),\quad -\frac{\pi}{2} \lt\phi \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$E(\rho,\phi) = -E_{\rho}(\rho),\quad \frac{\pi}{2} \lt \phi \lt \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

The $z$ component of the curl of this field is thus

$$(\nabla \times \vec E)\cdot \hat z = -\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial E(\rho,\phi)}{\partial \phi}$$

This is zero except at $\phi = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ where it is 'infinite' at the discontinuity.

You can see this in the picture without resorting to math.  Along the horizontal line, the field lines above the line are opposite those below the line.  A closed line integral of the field that goes above and below the line will be non-zero.

Thus, since the field is not irrotational, this cannot be the field of a static charge configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with this:

Charges are the sources of the electric field. So, whatever the point that field lines are "created" or "destroyed", must be a charge. Then, if there are a charge, then must be on the center.

Calculating the electric flux:
$$ 
\phi = \iint_S\ \mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf s = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}
$$

Let's pick a sphere as gaussian surface. From the draw, seems reasonable to assume $\phi = 0$, since half of field lines are entering, and half are leaving. If there's no flux, there's no charge.

Then $Q = 0$. There are "two" possibilities: Equal charges $+q$ and $-q$ forming up infinitesimal dipole, or no charges. Since this field configuration is not dipole, then must have no charges.

Of course could be more complex configuration of charges, like "quadrupoles" and so on. This are not possible too, because the field lines are being created and destroyed in the same point, without existance of a "symmetry line".

If there's no charge, there's no field lines. Then, this field configuration seems to be impossible.